# Iterating over google places JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-places-api

Hi I have been able to get the JSON response back from google places and need to extract the photo reference element from it.

I have tried to iterate over the places results and for each places results the photo_reference but i get the error message.

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' or undefined.

**What I have tried:**

```js
    response.on('end', function() {
      var places = JSON.parse(body);
      var locations = places.results;
      
      locations.forEach(function(loc) {
          var photoRef = loc.photos[0].photo_reference;
          console.log('Photo ref ==' + photoRef);
                
      });
    });
```

Here is a sample of the JSON response.

```js
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 46.7725141,
               "lng" : 23.62686099999999
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 46.77284264999999,
                  "lng" : 23.62798785
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 46.77152845000001,
                  "lng" : 23.62348045
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
         "id" : "18ce6ff7131f1ffd9ce9b2558ba407eed7409aee",
         "name" : "Hotel Univers T",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1066,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116854836566418330262/photos\"\u003eHotel Univers T\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAE6Zi31LvtXmRM0orTBKDbJ3pgENKS82rVyP-462YhvrZAhhiDp2xowEiWsDNPU8tTmkXkhhB2ADKHi5GcptXSDx16GtG6RL9gpmogJw9BIR1JDiWSgMOzIE9xguxAQJ_s6Q9VHv77tQAmukc7JTJmBF_bFKQF3pVcmH6ffuUuiZEhDaF5BmQFqZRyeDOAA0KBkdGhSYpD-28mHr9XOKRb8dTheHJLA5bg",
               "width" : 1069
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJPzw_f2oMSUcRNl_Mz_sQS2c",
         "rating" : 4,
         "reference" : "CmRRAAAAGFISd-ET8V96LNII_v7yz5W80IuYIkLPyEPkf2dXWXudbM8YOfzaLDGMV1oNFl2YpN6dWEIDGl4TmAFP2wEYHPklveu-fXdFjUWA-w5cKapzxv0fdhSlSk4HkzpG9YN8EhDuT1KZUzs-O2h_eIjhgu5_GhSND6qUA9VG54QBT3csNWMaG_75Lw",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "gym",
            "spa",
            "lodging",
            "health",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "Strada Alexandru Vaida Voevod 53-55, Cluj-Napoca"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 46.7720145,
               "lng" : 23.6257946
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 46.77209325,
                  "lng" : 23.62638825
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 46.77177825,
                  "lng" : 23.62401364999999
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "61f80d1a74e00b55a075cacde6fc95aa88bfa83f",
         "name" : "Pizza Hut Iulius Mall",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2322,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112054611800145890609/photos\"\u003etamara ionescu\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAOdAY1sLwHqWZ1sEFvhZrqAoFCNo7DbthSnLMn1aI6lGxmGhfJdE7dLFDsJxjwSyh_0L3F2Mf_-Si12UmJ9CtaySu6SjHrqnaoF1WdafNDNLbkDbqjvesU0FqJid9V8poKU8Hhtb2PAvRe8lkfJF6N1ujIWWOxQlRfhHdjqN_BAAEhCTFmdXtQjfWiC3qbOZO3SqGhTIsansBf4AxGYnt6FnoslOVrqtyw",
               "width" : 4128
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ-0XLwGoMSUcR87bDPcmCLHI",
         "price_level" : 1,
         "rating" : 4.1,
         "reference" : "CmRRAAAAby6PokNes7fY7vSBVfxZvOfZj5wehpXYD8oUFAYRgmyOwreZ-hsxByGOCb0SRRfD73muHIScP0lK7fVlMk7g2-B1tOqxHt60oDKPkfgbe42QogLNVDnAmjo1nGrtHGzUEhB9TPDl0pw_CSCpmcQkERp8GhT_kUf3Xb1CQLliMvvc_BStebrt_w",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Strada Alexandru Vaida Voevod 55, Cluj-Napoca"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 46.7731014,
               "lng" : 23.627801
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "32a93ffe70bbdd2c8485e346837ad61384e67bf1",
         "name" : "Hanul Dacilor",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2988,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102010465058487677046/photos\"\u003eחוסין מוחמד\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAALGMxPZEorGPgWzFhEX8GQ6KWqvl1Gs5s4w8n0-_wyFWNQ2AaxbUXjIZK_EXnEbI6UCM4YhVyjdObdpVyEtJ6oMJ1MG_GtW_BJi2Mc-75PPBX500rAbAy_jz-8L9NL4pdC1wHF6cwWj08xx2zBHammjvvB-DD_yeSjP5qt-GV09PEhDhOXdgy57rEKjg0N5pZ01CGhTeRa3PSqE-RkpI5vGjdDObho2AwQ",
               "width" : 5312
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJmRm5HmsMSUcRLIcHKiIRKmY",
         "rating" : 4.4,
         "reference" : "CmRRAAAA1mC_ed2g3YhFhzsrY8fXgE4Xida9jQ9BxpIk6raJpNmFUEJn00JciB3PRisZfOCpB3034vayac5_dqY8Bp_eQnS1HBSC0IdQp_Hu4Dcb_krbWQs6Sl7bTVSD5Rsu9LqmEhCDZdOMO2YJCNCh7n3-t0qbGhTI9ibzMsLx0OQUQ_oihQkUdr_Yhg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Iulius Mall, Strada Alexandru Vaida Voevod 53-55, Cluj-Napoca"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 46.771945,
               "lng" : 23.626012
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "8d7bb32fd50d968c79c2e5048c12b95cec8cbb7d",
         "name" : "Marty City",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1125,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114164649734885665448/photos\"\u003eMarty City\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CoQBcwAAAAfjwkLAWX73DgVUjKgP2uS39gFUilk6CrHCfdy-V4d1ZJrdZKzHOeqNqU0f5gHy9-MWeNGsY_2q7cJpi_b9_5oYneyQWs4U-zN6l5DxpeMdtrnNuNwd31b3BA_IEy7q_JZ8IlMScrqRspSBmq6tfFaTdnNZUwr0acvEOCVnwp2MEhCw0oErjn23GJoa5knp4gZuGhQ5ztJ1RbSe1zJbhCzAqJvAm-fN-Q",
               "width" : 1500
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJU22Cv2oMSUcR-rhmfyKJixA",
         "rating" : 3.8,
         "reference" : "CmRRAAAAHjaKSuIN_npID0s-cC2oJAJxwLZv-sOz0J9OW8AdiRzoqlQE1MMKH3aWDwKLB9P18uGxzgefxBnkc1_E4s-4gpJsTdmoATlxSoxsuQPGl4W0pXVHBZzpnvPHCSK5GyHEEhDarUaahHk1WNi7jzExovQ3GhS-KvRprEN1uPj-cw6PJcIqiDhl8A",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "str. Alexandru Vaida Voievod 53, Cluj-Napoca"
      },
```

Comment: I think sometimes, there is no photo object in the response (can exist for places without photos). Can you check if this is the case by printing the entire response to console and see if it exists for each location. I have tried it here - https://repl.it/EW5r/0 and it seems to work fine for response example you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. Maybe you should try testing for the existence of the `photos` array before accessing it:

```
locations.forEach(function(loc) {
    var photoRef;
    if (loc.photos && Array.isArray(loc.photos)) {
        photoRef = loc.photos[0].photo_reference;
    }
    else {
        photoRef = "No photo in data!";
    }

    console.log('Photo ref == ' + photoRef);
});
```